# Replacing a static Enum with a HashMap or similar

Tags: rust

I have a simple Enum used to map to hardcoded strings:

Think:

```
enum SomeThing {
   A, B, C
}
```

These values are shown in a UI as RadioButtons so the user can pick one and these options are mapped to a string (the name of a file I don't control).

The way this is done at runtime time is (pseudo-code):

```
let xxx: HashMap::from([
    (
       SomeThing::A.to_string(),
       "value_for_a".to_string(),
    ),
    (
       SomeThing::B.to_string(),
       "value_for_b".to_string(),
   ),
   etc...
```

This is done at runtime and later used to retrieve the value for the chosen option. The fact that it's an Enum has the type safety in mind. But...

I'd like to change this code to make it user-configurable, and allow the user to specify those values themselves; since it's a runtime-constructed `HashMap`, I could imagine a config file (of any format like YAML) having:

```
---
xxx:
  A: value_for_a
  B: value_for_b
  C: value_for_c
```

And parsed into "the same" HashMap (without the benefits of the Enum type safety).

The questions are:

1. I suppose creating an Enum at runtime would not be possible right? I'd imagine the user could create a new `D` key/value and or remove an existing one.
2. What would be another way to do this instead? Keep/Use a HashMap of some sort to store the Key (A,B,C) and their values after they were parsed?
   (*worth mentioning: the Enum is *convenient* because it's used by `structopt` [for a command line parameter via the provided `arg_enum!` macro](https://ruststudy.github.io/tao_of_rust_docs/structopt/clap/macro.arg_enum.html), so you can specify the `posible_values` as `&YourEnum::variants()` but this is less important to keep*)
3. Is there a "better" way to do this that you can think of?

Comment: Conceptually it should be possible to load a config file into a hashmap and have its keys be defined to be arguments (and even be present in the help menu).

Comment: Got any _pointer_ to this conceptual info? ;)

Comment: Seems like this might be relevant, [lazy_static](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/) ? Part of the lazy evaulation logic could load values from a config file.

Comment: For the CLI, if you're using `clap`, you can manually set the possible values: https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.Arg.html#method.value_parser. So, you'd just load up your config file and then populate the available values.